# How to set up a Mercurial repo like BitBucket on a Linux machine?

Tags: linux, mercurial

I've been using for a while BitBucket as a repo. Now I'd like to set up my own repository and I'd like it to have similar functionalities (in particular I'd like to push, have some kind of web interface, etc...).

How would you do this? Are there any *easy* solutions?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you'd like to give RhodeCode http://rhodecode.org/ a try.

Comment: +1 for RhodeCode. Do you recommend it?

Answer (score 2):

[SCM-Manager](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/Home):

> The easiest way to share and manage your Git, Mercurial and Subversion repositories over http.
>
> - Very easy installation
> - No need to hack configuration files, SCM-Manager is completely configureable from its Web-Interface
> - No Apache and no database installation is required
> - Central user, group and permission management
> - Out of the box support for Git, Mercurial and Subversion
> - Full RESTFul Web Service API (JSON and XML)
> - Rich User Interface
> - Simple Plugin API
> - Useful plugins available ( f.e. Ldap-, ActiveDirectory-, PAM-Authentication)

Answer (score 0):

I started using mercurial via bitbucket also, it's a really great service. We do the following:

For browsing, in the repository directory, the `hg serve` command will serve you up the repo on port 8000 by default. That gives you the web interface/search/code highlighting, On my Windows PC I can then do `hg clone` and I've got a backup of the repo. That's for free all built in to mercurial, you can enable an unauthenticated push but that's not on by default and I've not used it (see URL). The other nice thing is that it's only serving when you have the `serve` command running. Repo is on linux so the push is handled by ssh which we have integrated with Active Directory at work.

See this URL for some push solutions:

http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories