# Is there a Mercurial admin web frontend?

Tags: untagged

Something like Bitbucket (of course much less feature-rich). It must be able to hold multiple repositories, and be private (i.e. if you don't login, it doesn't show you anything).

It should be able to run on a Linux server, and if it's also easy to setup (like phpMyAdmin) it would of course be better.

phpHgAdmin seems abandoned and doesn't even have a website, and the others I've seen mentioned don't look very promising. This is usually a sign that "it doesn't exists", but maybe I just didn't search well enough.

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/287512/how-to-set-up-a-mercurial-repo-like-bitbucket-on-a-linux-machine/290939#290939 recommends http://rhodecode.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SCM-Manager](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/Home):

> The easiest way to share and manage your Git, Mercurial and Subversion repositories over http.
>
> - Very easy installation
> - No need to hack configuration files, SCM-Manager is completely configureable from its Web-Interface
> - No Apache and no database installation is required
> - Central user, group and permission management
> - Out of the box support for Git, Mercurial and Subversion
> - Full RESTFul Web Service API (JSON and XML)
> - Rich User Interface
> - Simple Plugin API
> - Useful plugins available ( f.e. Ldap-, ActiveDirectory-, PAM-Authentication)

Comment: Looks very interesting, much more polished than rhodecode... I'll try it, thanks!

Comment: It is also simpler to set up than RhodeCode, since SCM-Manager is kind of self-contained: just add java and you're done.

Answer (score 5):

[RhodeCode](http://rhodecode.org/) is a great Bitbucket-like tool you can install yourself.

I like it: it's under heavy development but is already very feature full. I recently installed it for a client and they see good performance with it. They are ~65 developers and have ~50 machines in a build farm that pull from the RhodeCode server.

Comment: (a pity I didn't manage to install on OSX, though)

Comment: Please contact the RhodeCode developers on their normal mailing list — that's a much better way to ask for support.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays [Phabricator](http://phabricator.org/) looks like a good solution - apparently you can disable any modules you don't want, such as code review, wiki etc.